# Angularjs notification showing twice if on 2 browser tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser, notifications, web-notifications

I am using [angular-web-notification](https://github.com/sagiegurari/angular-web-notification) . My problem is that if I open 2 browser tabs and then the messages are received, I get to see two instances of notifications shown.

Below is the reference code.

```js
    webNotification.showNotification(title, {
        body: body,
        onClick: function onNotificationClicked() {
            console.log('Notification clicked.');
        },
        icon: 'icon.png'
    }, function onShow(error, hide) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Unable to show notification: ' + error.message);
        } else {
            console.log('Notification Shown.');
        }
    });
```

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent any duplicate notification use Tag

Notification.tag
The ID of the notification
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification

```
 webNotification.showNotification(title, {
        body: body,
        tag:"some custom unique tag per notification"
        onClick: function onNotificationClicked() {
            console.log('Notification clicked.');
        },
        icon: 'icon.png'
    }, function onShow(error, hide) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Unable to show notification: ' + error.message);
        } else {
            console.log('Notification Shown.');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @Aian Can you please explain the method that be named the tags?

Comment: [...Array(30)].map(() => Math.random().toString(36)[2]).join('')
you can use any random string when you send the notification ,BTW the tag should generate server side (I assume you send notification from server) the same source where (title , body) come

Comment: Thank you again @Aian

Answer (score -1):

In my case i had got the push notification twice, but i solved that before.
At the moment, i have one question for you now, do you use fcm ?

Comment: No, I use the websocket.

Comment: Can you please explain you solution?

Comment: Hi! Please explain your solution instead of asking a question, it will be far more useful to all of us. Thanks!